# line-through style not working

Tags: css, angularjs

I wanted to display the text of a button as line-through if it satisfies a certain condition.  I have the following code in html:

```
<div class="col col-80" >
    <button  ng-class="{'fulfilled': item.itemStatus!='OPEN'}" class="row" ng-disabled="item.itemStatus!='OPEN'">{{item.displaydetail}} {{item.itemStatus}}</button> 
</div>
```

I have also defined the class in my css as follows:

```
.fulfilled {
text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

However, when I run the application, the button is disabled but the button text does not show the line-through.  What could be the problem here?

PS.  When I looked at the Element using Chrome inspect, I can see that the button class is correctly set to 'fulfilled'

Comment: Seems like people are running to earn points instead of paying real attention in your problem, that's a pity. I made a jsfiddle for your problem, and it turned out, I didn't change anything in your code and it is wortking ! See here : http://jsfiddle.net/fuwL7Loj/1/

Comment: @Alburkerk result in your answer is nothing.what thing you solved?

Comment: see new edited code.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ADukg/13390/) your code working just fine

Comment: Well he just asks for a button with line-through only when it is disable right ? That's what my fiddle does :/ And Durga's too

Comment: ok, so maybe there are other problems that might be causing the button not to show the line-through?  I just don't understand how it works in fiddle but the same code does not work on my app.

Answer (score 0):

If the `button` is disabled style will apply,

```css
button:disabled {
text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="col col-80">
  <button ng-class="{'fulfilled': item.itemStatus!='OPEN'}" class="row" ng-disabled="item.itemStatus!='OPEN'">{{item.displaydetail}} {{item.itemStatus}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what he asks for

Answer (score 0):

Please add new css class.

```
button {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Or

```
button.row {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i actually don't wan't to style the element itself.  I just wanted to have a specific style for the class.

Comment: Then please add new class like class="row div-custom" and add this  text-decoration: line-through; property to newly added class.

Comment: isn't this what my code is already doing?  it's just weird that id does not work on my code but it does work in fiddle.

Comment: It would be good if you will provide reason what's wrong in above code. So we will improve quality of the code.

Comment: i am not saying there is anything wrong with your code or with your suggestion.  But it does not solve the problem in my application.  I don't know why it's not working in my code when the fiddle sample above works independently.  I am not actually sure if I can solve my problem but I will keep trying.